# Import 3rd party module into Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, js-amd

I am trying to import this module into an Ember.js (**version 2.5**) app:

https://github.com/hapijs/nes/blob/master/lib/client.js

This is how I'm doing it (following the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/)):

```
app.import('bower_components/nes/lib/client.js', { exports: { 'nes': ['default', 'client'] } });
```

And the import declaration:

```
import client from 'nes';
```

Now I keep getting the error below:

> loader.js:201 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `nes` imported
>   from `myapp.com/components/chart-widget`

I assume the import statement is right and the actual module doesn't export itself in a way Ember can consume it. However, how can I fix it? Is there a way to write a wrapper around 3rd party libraries such as this one?

Comment: Can you paste the line from `component/chart-widget` where you actually import your module ?

Comment: Please see updated question. I have also tried importing like import { client } from 'nes' and import nes from 'nes' but didn't really work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL:DR your module is accessible as a global variable with `nes.Client`.

You are looking at the wrong section in the guide. `hapijs/nes` is not a standard AMD asset and thus cannot be directly imported using the `import` keyword. This means that your library is to be found in the global context.

Debugging through `bower_components/nes/lib/client.js` will show you that  the code is branching in this case : https://github.com/hapijs/nes/blob/master/lib/client.js#L24

You can simply access your third party module via a global variable named `nes.Client`.

If you'd like to access it with the ES6 `import` keyword for more clarity, you can generate a vendor-shim as describe in the guide : https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies.

Note that this will not remove `nes` from the global context and will just allow you to import it with the `import` keyword.